# Whats wrong in the following XML file

Tags: java, xml, struts2

I have the following error with my XML file below it...I'm developing a small Struts2 web app on eclipse and I have tried looking up several posts about this error and I have put the "filter" and "filter-mapping" within the "web-app" tag...but I have the following error being displayed.

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Below is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns  
/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>blah!</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

What is the problem here....I think I have ended the tags properly..I cannot figure that out

Comment: Maybe funny characters in the XML? Look at it with a binary editor?

Comment: treid...no errors found....anything else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this attributes at begin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

And change the nodes order, like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: i really dont know whats the reason...but this worked perfectly....can u put explain the reason in brief or can u give me any links to it....thanks a ton !

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Link: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/
Hope it help u!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a syntax error. I validated it here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Maybe the problem is in the way you process it.

Comment: Your XML is not the problem. It's well formed. I think the error comes with the code you are using to load this xml. Can you edit your post with these code?

Comment: its working right now...thank u :).......all i did was re-enter the same xml code....clean the project....and I really dont know why it worked :O!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the order of element the well-formed document should have a correct order of elements. To fix your problem reformat it with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>blah!</display-name>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...it did not work..its showing the same error as above....anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the XML file you have shown us is well-formed, and yet a respectable piece of software is saying your XML is not well-formed, I would pursue the hypothesis that the XML it is complaining about is not the XML you have shown us.

Comment: sir...I have checked it....its the same file ....I will upload my whole code very shortly from now

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the  tag with below code snip**

```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```